# .NET 6.0: Getting CS8600 warning when assigning null to a variable of type object

Tags: c#

Each lines of the following code produces `CS8600` warning in .NET 6.0 (two warnings in total):

```
object x = null;
string s = null;
```

**CS8600    Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.**

I don't get the same warning when I compile the code under .NET 3.1

This must be due to a change since .NET 3.1. What is the concept that I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

You have the [Nullable Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) feature enabled. For new projects targeting .Net 6 and onwards, this is on by default.

This feature changes the default of reference types to not accept null assignment, and produces compiler warnings when you try to assign null. You now need to indicate to the compiler that you expect this type to contain a null value.

```
object? x = null;
string? s = null;
```

This is the simplified version of *one* of the aspects of the feature. Read the documentation page for more details.